# How do I set environment variables so that they execute when calling WSL from PowerShell?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First let me clarify the question. I'm not asking how to sync environment variables. What I am asking is how to set `JAVA_HOME` so that when I call `` wsl echo `$JAVA_HOME `` from powershell it writes out the specified bash environment variable.

So far, I've tried setting the value in `/etc/environments`. I've also tried setting the value in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. The command I'm executing in both of those startup scripts is: `export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/java"`

The WSL OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3

What am I missing. Surely there must be a way to set environment variables. If I execute something like `` wsl echo `$PATH ``, I get a value.